# Add css class before image load

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load

I have container with background image.

How can i add css class to this container before background image loads?

Now i add class (*New*) using JQuery on **document.ready** to overload css rules of another class (*Base*). 
On **Load**, image appears firstly with css of class *Base*, and than display acording to class *New*. 
Problem : i can see when image is stretching on screen.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.content-wrap').addClass('home-view');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
$('<img/>').attr('src', 'http://www.yoursite.com/yourpicture.png').load(function() {
  $(this).remove();
  $('.content-wrap').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.yoursite.com/yourpicture.png)');
});
```

Regards.

Comment: thanks for reply. `.content-wrap` - isn't container that have background-image. but in context of `.content-wrap.home-view` i have css rules, that i want.